# Expected value and Variance of $Y=\frac{1}{a} X-b$ where $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$

Tags: probability, statistics

I absolutely know I am not doing this right. :[

Could I get some input or point back in the right direction?

My work done so far is shown below.

> Let $X$ be a normal random variable with parameters $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Please find the Expected value and Variance of random variable $Y=\frac{1}{a} X-b$, where $a$ and $b$ are constant values.

**My work.**

$$
\begin{align*}
E(Y) &= aE(x)-b = \sum_x \Big(\frac{1}{a} x - b \Big) p_x(x) = \frac{1}{a} \sum_x x p_x(x) - b 
\\ &=  \frac{1}{a} \sum_x x p_x(x) - b \sum_x p_x(x) = a E(x) - b \cdot 1.
\end{align*}
$$

If $a = 0$, then $E(x-b) = E(x)$ and if $b = 0$, then $E(ax)= \frac{1}{a}E(x)$.

$$
\begin{align*}
\mu &= E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x) dx = \int_{0}^{1} x \Big(\frac{1}{a} X - b \Big) dx = \frac{1}{a} \int_0^1 X^2 - xb ~dx 
\\ & = \frac{1}{a} \Big( \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{bx^2}{2} \Big) \text{ from } 1 \text{ to } 0 
\\ & = \frac{1}{a} \Big( \frac{1}{3} - \frac{b}{2} \Big) .
\end{align*}
$$

$$
\text{RV } Y = (X - E(x)^2).
$$

$$
\sigma^2 = \operatorname{Var}(x) = E[(x) - E[x])^2]
$$

$$
\operatorname{Var} \Big( \frac{1}{a} X - b \Big) = a^2 \operatorname{Var}(x).
$$
$$
\int_{\Box}^{\Box}\Big( \frac{1}{a} X - b \Big) - \Big( \frac{1}{a} X - b \Big)^2 \ldots
$$

Comment: Hint:  set $1/a = c$.  What is $E[cX-b]$?  What is the value of $E[cX-b]$ when $X$ is _not_ a normal random variable?

Comment: E[cX-b] is similar to E[ax+b] for the discrete RV... I think I have been hooked on the discrete random variable being similar, and am not sure where to go with the actual normal random variable.

Comment: I have typed out the text as in the image. There are several mistakes as it stands. @Ubez Please make appropriate modifications if you are able to find any of the errors.

Comment: Yea, thank you Srivatsan. x[

Comment: I have looked at the original post. Maybe it was typed hurriedly. It is full of errors, some of which ($x$ instead of $X$) point to major difficulties.  You seem to be unable to apply the formula $E(aX+b)=aE(X)+b$, which you were given, to the minor variant $E(\frac{1}{a}X-b)$. And there are many other substantial misunderstandings.

Answer (score 4):

Since expectation is linear, you have that $\mathsf{E}(Y)=\mathsf{E}(1/a\:X-b)=1/a\:\mathsf{E}(X)-b$.  Furthermore,

$$
\begin{align}
\mathsf{Var}(Y)
&=\mathsf{E}(Y^{\;2})-\mathsf{E}(Y)^2\\
&=\mathsf{E}(1/a^2X^2-2b/aX+b^2)-(1/a\:\mathsf{E}(X)-b)^2\\
&=1/a^2\mathsf{E}(X^2)-2b/a\mathsf{E}(X)+b^2-1/a^2\mathsf{E}(X)^2+2b/a\mathsf{E}(X)-b^2\\
&=1/a^2\mathsf{E}(X^2)-1/a^2\mathsf{E}(X)^2\\
&=1/a^2\mathsf{Var}(X).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: That is only for discrete random variables though, isn't it? I feel like a normal random variable should be handled differently. Also, this doesn't fit into the E[aX+b] formula because it is a negative b. Sorry, I'm just trying to understand.

Comment: These hold no matter what the distribution of $X$ is.

Comment: Okay, I'll go for it then. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Srivatsan: thanks. I don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\operatorname{var}\left( \frac 1 a X - b\right) = \operatorname{var}\left( \frac 1 a X \right) = \frac 1 {a^2} \operatorname{var}(X).
$$
$$
\operatorname E\left( \frac 1 a X-b\right) = \frac 1 a \operatorname E(X) - b.
$$